# nginx match location with regex

Tags: regex, nginx

I have been trying to figure out whats wrong with my `regex` or nginx `config`. I have the following location block in my nginx config

```
location ~ /v1/(tests|my/.*/tests|your/.*/test|our/.*/testers) {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

Nginx is running on port `8080` and i have a simple test web server running on port `8000`. I was testing this with the following paths

- `http://localhost:8080/v1/tests` (Works)
- `http://localhost:8080/v1/my/a1/tests` (Works)
- `http://localhost:8080/v1/my/%20/tests` (Works)
- `http://localhost:8080/v1/my//tests` (Fails with **404** on nginx server)
- `http://localhost:8080/v1/my/%2F/tests` (Fails with **404** on nginx server)

I was wondering why this is, since i was matching with `my/.*/tests`, which should have matched empty string too? Am i missing something?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: You have writtent `testers` instead of `tests` in your regex.

Comment: Which server generates the 404?

Comment: @RichardSmith The server running nginx returns **404**

Comment: @MayurKoshti `testers` is part of different path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nginx` normalises the URI before performing tests (such as regex). Part of the normalisation process is to fold consecutive `/`s into a single `/`.

The result is that `my/tests` is not a valid match for your regex.

Comment: Thank you, just adding the reference here, http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location